# positively identifying http requests from java HttpClient

Tags: php, android, httpclient

I am building an Android app that communicates with a remote server to get data. How can I use PHP to positively identify a request coming from an `HttpClient` Android app?

One might think to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`, but that can be easily spoofed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it matter if someone spoofs the `HTTP_USER_AGENT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android Developers Blog has an in depth posting on identifying applications: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

The basic idea is to have the Android app generate a unique identifier when it is installed.  You can pass that to the server when making requests.  In your case, it might not need to be unique on a per installation basis though.